# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $.data

Tags: android, retrofit

I am getting exception as `retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $.data`

I am requesting data as :

```
        RestAdapter loginAdapter = Utils.buildAdapter();
                final ApiConfig signUpApi = loginAdapter.create(ApiConfig.class);
                signUpApi.signUp(new SignupDetailResponse.SignUpDetailRequestBody(email, password, AppConstants.DEVICE_TOKEN, AppConstants.DEVICE_TYPE),
                                new Callback<SignupDetailResponse.SignUpResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(SignupDetailResponse.SignUpResponseBody signUpDetailResponse, Response response) {
                        Long responseCode = signUpDetailResponse.responseCode;
                        Utils.SHOW_TOAST(context, responseCode.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                        if (retrofitError.getResponse() != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, retrofitError.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

where in `Utils`,

```
public static RestAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(AppConfig.API_BASE_URL)
            .build();

}
```

My interface :

```
public interface ApiConfig {

  @POST("/signUp")
  public void signUp(@Body SignupDetailResponse.SignUpDetailRequestBody signUpDetailRequestBody, Callback<SignupDetailResponse.SignUpResponseBody> signUpDetailResponseCallback);

}
```

My LoginResponse:

```
package com.shubham.network.response;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class SignupDetailResponse {

 public static class SignUpDetailRequestBody {

    final String email;
    final String password;
    final String acType;
    final String deviceType;

    public SignUpDetailRequestBody(String email, String password, String acType, String deviceType) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.acType = acType;
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
    }

}

public static class SignUpResponseBody {

    @Expose
    public String data;

    @Expose
    public Boolean success;

    @Expose
    public String message;

    @Expose
    public Long responseCode;

    /**
     * @return The data
     */
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @return The success
     */
    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * @return The message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * @return The responseCode
     */
    public Long getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }
}
}
```

Expected JSON response :

```
{
"data": "1",
"success": true,
"message": "You have successfully SignUp. Please login to your registered email and activate your account",
"responseCode": 8
}
```

I think I have build my model correctly. I have also added retrofit(1.9.0) and gson(2.3.1) JARS in my project.

Comment: Can you get the raw JSON response from the server? The exception states that some of the expected string properties in the response is, in fact, a JSON object. I guess it is `data` or `message`, but having the raw response is going to show the real cause of the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have included this in my question itself. The expected response is also the actual response I am getting when I hit the API using Postman.